# Low level control of HDD head positioning

Tags: firmware

I want to use an HDD mechanics as a tool for precise positioning. Does Ubguntu have tools to issue hard drive commands like "move head to this position" or "spin 90 degrees" ?

Comment: That's not how an HDD controller works so it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of fine control can only be achieved by a custom firmware for a hard drive. Some drives don't support "flashing" of the firmware. Seagate provides some tools for updating firmware images. The community has some information on the existing [commands in the firmware](https://web.archive.org/web/20181213045825/http://elabz.com/forums/electronics-repairs/list-of-seagate-firmware-terminal-commands/), but overall drives do not provide that specific of control. The closest you're going to get is basically telling the drive to "sweep" the platter which happens at a known constant rate.